# Is IE 32-bit by default? even on 64-bit machines?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, vpn, internet-explorer, activex

I know this is a simple question, but I am having trouble finding a clear answer. Is IE 32-bit by default even if you're running a 64-bit Windows OS? It seems that that is the case, even on Windows 8, but I can't find a clear message that states just that.

The problem is that I am refactoring a webpage embedded VPN ActiveX control, and need to decide if I need to use an entirely different technology or not.

Comment: Related: [Why is IEx64 not the default for x64 Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/52874/why-is-iex64-not-the-default-for-x64-windows?rq=1).

Comment: Short answer, "Yes, it's still the default".  But in reality, your question is off-topic, as it is dependant on a time-frame ("still" may not be accurate in a couple years), you're basically asking for product information, and there's no actual problem presented, so I'm voting got close.

Comment: The problem presented is that jumpdart doesn't know if 32-bit IE is the default on Windows 8 x64. Since it's a reasonably-scoped question about computer software which can be answered definitively, it is on-topic.  http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I did reword it a bit to make it sound a little more legitimate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is 32 bit by default for plugin compatibility reasons.  Per comment by Microsoft:

> On 64-bit Windows 8, the browser frame process (both “modern UI” and
>   Desktop) runs 64-bit. However, for compatibility with plug-ins, IE 10
>   on the desktop runs 32-bit tabs by default.  If the user turns on
>   “Enhanced Protected Mode” in Internet Options, Advanced; they will
>   have 64-bit tabs by default for IE 10 on the Desktop.

[Source](http://www.neowin.net/news/how-to-enable-64-bit-ie10-for-the-desktop-in-windows-8)