# Accessing web address via Run Dialog

Tags: browser, run-dialog

I am experiencing a strange behavior when trying to access a web page by typing its address in Windows Run Dialog. Usually, when I just open the Run Dialog (<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and type in a web page address, the default browser will automatically be launched and will browse to that address. At the moment, I am doing the same thing on a new system and the following happens:

1. The default browser launches(IE8 if that matters)
2. It looks like it's navigating to the relevant webpage
3. The screen stays blank and the "Connecting..." title just being displayed on the tab.

When I navigate to the same address normally; by first launching the browser that takes me to its home page and just then entering the actual address - everything works as expected.

The question is what is the difference between those 2 methods. I would think they are absolutely identical. But it seems that the address or the browser are handled differently when launching it from Run Dialog rather than manually. Could it be that the browser is somehow launched with different settings compared to when it's launched manually?

**EDIT**:
I have just noticed that when I run the address from Run Dialog, the process in Task Manager looks like that:

[image]

When I run the IE directly (clicking on from Start menu) the process looks different:
[image]

So I guess something somewhere points to a wrong location. Where is that defined and how to changes that?

Comment: When you run the "Run" version it's running the (usually default) 32-Bit IE and when you click the IE icon it's running the 64-Bit version. I'm surprised that the 32-Bit one is doing this. Have you tried resting the browser settings in IE control panel ("Advanced" tab)?

Comment: @BigChris Hi and thanks for your comment. Yes I realized that this is the difference (32 bit vs 64 bit). It looks like an expected behavior (take a look here: http://superuser.com/q/52874/111772). The question is how to make 64 but the default?

Comment: @BigChris Not sure what "Advanced tab" you were talking about?