# How to define what IE is going to be launched by default (32 bit vs 64 bit)

Tags: internet-explorer, default-settings

Following my previous question [here](https://superuser.com/q/890942/111772), how do I define what browser will be opened by default when running a web address from Run Dialog? At the moment my issue is that at the moment it opens the 32 bit version from the `Program Files (x86)` folder. I would like it to run the 64 bit version from `Program Files` folder. How do I define it?

I tried:

1. Change `*.html` extension association
2. Mark the 64bit IE as the default browser

None of the above helped.

**P.S.** the same happens when I just open a local *.html page. I tried to edit the extension associations but that had no effect.

Comment: How?  You launch it using the full path then set it to the default browser.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, thanks for the comment. This is what I did right now, launched it from Run Dialog with full path preceding the web address but I want to avoid doing that. How can I set it as a default browser in that manner? It's still IE so it won't offer that automatically.

Comment: Set it through the registry.

Comment: Have you tried?  If you have what have you tried?  If you have not tried [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813058/windows-regkey-default-browser-application-path) are some ways you can.